# Cant make the second 74HC595 to start counting

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I'm doing my first project with Arduino, however I got in a block and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This project is 'simple'. It's that Stranger Thing's Wall.

However, I want to use the 74HC595 to leave pins free on the arduino for maybe expand and do something else with that too, so, I tried doing the arduino tutorial (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/ShiftOut)

So my current schematic is this one below

[image]

My code, however, is kind of a frankenstein. I used the shiftOut from the tutorials, however I must confess I do not know how it works (And I think its where the error may lie). I do know VBA and Python, but I know nothing of C (Or whichever this language is)

```
    //Pin connected to ST_CP of 74HC595
#define latchPin 5
//Pin connected to SH_CP of 74HC595
#define clockPin 7
////Pin connected to DS of 74HC595
#define dataPin 6
String text;                                                    //Variável do tipo string que receberá o texto
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                           //Velocidade de comunicação
  for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);                                   //Declarando o pino como saída
  }
  Serial.println("Iniciando");
  inicializationEffect();                                       //Chamada da Função responsável pelo efeito inicial
  //basicTest();
}
void loop() {
  

  receiveText();                                               //Chamada da função responsável por receber o texto digitado
}
//Função que recebe o texto diitado
void receiveText() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {                              //Verifica se existe alguma informação na Serial
    char c = Serial.read();                                     //atribui cada caractere a variável c que é do tipo char
    if (c != '\n') text.concat(c) ;                              //verifica se a variável do tipo char recebeu uma quebra de linha que indica o fim da palavra ou frase e concatena todos os caracteres na String text
    delay(10);                                                  //aguarda 10 milissegundos
  }
  if (text.length() > 0) {                                      //verifica se a string text tem tamanho maior que 0
    text.toUpperCase();                                       //transforma tudo que estiver na string text para maiúsculo
    if (text[0] == '#'){
      waveEffect();
    }else {
      executeEffect(text);                                        //chama a função executeEffect passando a string text como parâmetro
    }
  }
  text = "";                                                    //limpa a string text
}
//Função responsável por ativar linha que recebe como parâmetro o número da linha
void lineActivation(int line, int keepalive) {
  if (keepalive == 0) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
      digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    }
  }
    digitalWrite(line+1, HIGH);                               //coloca a linha 1 em estado lógico alto
}

void activateLetter(char letter, int on, int off) {
  int lt;
  lt = (((int)letter - 64) % 9);
  if (((int)letter - 64) > 8) {
    lt = lt + 1;
  }
  if (on) {
    callCol(1<<lt-1);
    delay(on);                                                //mantém o pino em nível lógico alto durante o tempo que foi determinado no parâmetro da função
  }
  if (off) {
    callCol(0);
    delay(off);                                               //mantém o pino em nível lógico baixo durante o tempo que foi determinado no parâmetro da função
  }

}

void callCol(int col){
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, 0);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, col);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);

}
void executeEffect(String text) {
  for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if (text[i] == ' ') {
      delay(1000);
    } else if ((int)text[i] < 65 or (int)text[i] > 90) {
    } else {
      lineActivation(int(((int)text[i] - 64) / 9) + 1, 0);
      activateLetter(text[i], 1000, 200);
    }
  }
}

void inicializationEffect() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
    lineActivation(int(i / 9) + 1, 0);                          //ativa a linha
    activateLetter(char(64 + i), 1000, 10);                   //ativa a letra
  }
}
void waveEffect() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    lineActivation(i, 1);                          //ativa a linha
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    activateLetter(char(72 + i), 100, 0);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    activateLetter(char(72 + i), 0, 100);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    lineActivation(i, 1);                          //ativa a linha
  }
}

void basicTest() {
  lineActivation(2,1);
    for (int i = 0; 1 < 500; i++) {
    callCol(255-i);
    delay(100);
    }
    
  
}


void shiftOut(int myDataPin, int myClockPin, byte myDataOut) {
// This shifts 8 bits out MSB first,
//on the rising edge of the clock,
//clock idles low
//internal function setup
int i=0;
int pinState;
pinMode(myClockPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(myDataPin, OUTPUT);
//clear everything out just in case to
//prepare shift register for bit shifting
digitalWrite(myDataPin, 0);
digitalWrite(myClockPin, 0);
//for each bit in the byte myDataOut&#xFFFD;
//NOTICE THAT WE ARE COUNTING DOWN in our for loop
//This means that %00000001 or "1" will go through such
//that it will be pin Q0 that lights.
for (i=7; i>=0; i--)  {
digitalWrite(myClockPin, 0);
//if the value passed to myDataOut and a bitmask result
// true then... so if we are at i=6 and our value is
// %11010100 it would the code compares it to %01000000
// and proceeds to set pinState to 1.
if ( myDataOut & (1<<i) ) {
pinState= 1;
}
else {
pinState= 0;
}
//Sets the pin to HIGH or LOW depending on pinState
digitalWrite(myDataPin, pinState);
//register shifts bits on upstroke of clock pin
digitalWrite(myClockPin, 1);
//zero the data pin after shift to prevent bleed through
digitalWrite(myDataPin, 0);
}
//stop shifting
digitalWrite(myClockPin, 0);
}
```

If I understood right (Which I may not) theoretically, when I send a value over 255, it should "overflow" to the next 74HC595, which would be used to light the ninth column.

Comment: why `shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, 0);`?

Comment: To ensure its clear, however I removed that line for the solution I posted

Comment: where did you get that idea?

Comment: I mean, I was wrong. But the point was to always set the Binary value to 0 before setting it to the correct value. Just as a Failsafe, however the more I deal with this I realize the less I know. It doesnt need a failsafe, right?

Answer (score 3):

Solved using https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/17093/37827

By removing the custom shiftOut function and changing my

```
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, 0);
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, col);
```

with

```
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, highByte(col));  
shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, lowByte(col));
```

Works like a charm

PS: Feel free to suggest something else, but this way it fixed my problem